# is there a way to run a .s file in geany (its not in the available selections)?

Tags: assembly, geany

I noticed that the .s extension is not in the new file creation for Geany. How can assembly language run in Geany then?

Please see image in the hyperlink below.

[Geany New File (does not have .s or assembly file selection)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hrhb.png)

Comment: Classically, capital s  (file.S) is the extension for handcrafted assembly. Lower case .s is for generated backend assembler.

Answer (score 1):

You can add file-type extensions in Geany's preferences following:

*Tools -> Configuration Files -> filetype_extensions.conf*

Full settings of a (new) file extension is described in [filetype-extensions](https://www.geany.org/manual/current/index.html#filetype-extensions) part of Geany's documentaction.